# Ionic build failed; invalid %JAVA_HOME% (android)

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework, build

I've searched around a bunch and could not find an answer that could help me.

[image: Initial output]

I get this message when building my Ionic project for Android. I have verified, that both `java -version` and `javac` work in the folder, so both are accessible via the %path%.

[image: Java functionality]

What can I do to resolve this, and did I miss something?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30497071/ionic-build-cant-find-jdk-set-in-java-home-even-though-it-is-the-only-java-inst

Comment: I already checked that question and it didn't resolve my issue

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Ionic but apparently it is not using %PATH% , it is using %JAVA_HOME%.  You need to set it.

1. Determine the directory of a Java JDK (not JRE) in your system.  It could be something like `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65`. Since `javac` responds, you must have a JDK in the path somewhere.  This directory will be the value for JAVA_HOME. (**NOTE:** This is not the same as the Java `bin` directory in the path! There should not be a `bin` on the end of the directory.)
2. Open the System page in your Control Panel.

   You can do this in various ways:

   - Open an Explorer window, right-click on **This PC** and click on **Properties** in the menu.
   - Open Control Panel, click on **System and Security**, click on **System**.
3. Click on **Advanced System Settings**.
4. The System Properties window opens. Select the **Advanced** tab.
5. Click on the **Environment Variables...** button.
6. The Environment Variables window opens. Look at the bottom section labeled **System Variables**.  You should see a variable named **JAVA_HOME** in the list.  If you have this variable, double-check that the directory in the value exists and is a valid JDK directory.
7. If you don't see **JAVA_HOME** in the list, click the **New...** button.  If **JAVA_HOME** is there but it's the wrong value, select JAVA_HOME in the list and click the **Edit...** button.
8. The New System Variable or Edit System Variable window will open (they look about the same.)  Enter "JAVA_HOME" for variable name and the JDK directory for variable value.  You can use the **Browse Directory...** button to make sure you have a valid directory for the value.
9. Click the **Okay** button on the New/Edit System Variable window, then the Environment Variables window, and then the System Properties window.
10. You will need to log out and log in again for the JAVA_HOME variable to take effect.